# How do I sort elements of {}?

Tags: javascript, html, object

How do I sort elements of {}?

for example

```
{id：'555555',name:'222222',tt:'66666'}
```

Become

```
{name:'222222',id：'555555',tt:'66666'}
```

Comment: it is already sorted in alphabetical order ..

Comment: Question is unclear, do you want to sort them by value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Comment: Objects have no order, sorting them is futile

Comment: Yeah, objects have no order, if you need sorted data you should be using an array for example

Comment: I want to put name in the first place

Answer (score 0):

As others have already explained, properties inside an object do not have any particular order. Yet, if you wish to access them in a particular order, you could sort [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
var obj = {zz: 'adsgasdh', id:'555555',name:'222222',tt:'66666'};

var sortedKeys = Object.keys(obj).sort();

console.log(sortedKeys);

sortedKeys.forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
});
```